# a Process hidden from the Process Monitor

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to create an application which will be reading and writing to files(C++/MFC). but I need the process not to appear in process monitor (which comes with SysInternals).

From the reactions of others, I now confirm that this seems "illegal". but that is the request of the client I'm dealing with. so, I guess I just have to satisfy the client's request.

Comment: Why does it matter if it shows up in Process Monitor?

Comment: sounds like a rootkit or keylogger or something equally ethically dubious to me

Comment: "Helo, please help me write a rootkit. PS plz sendz teh codez"...

Comment: re: update - I'd take a good, long look at what your client is asking you to do. What is the app they're setting up? Could it be construed as spyware/malware?

Comment: why on earth would a client ask for a process be hidden from Process Monitor? I can think of only one reason: they are doing something dubious.

Comment: We are working on another project. and they asked me yesterday wether I was able to this task fro them. so, I'm trying as maybe the future of our relationship might be boosted by this.

Comment: yeah it does sound like a malicious thing they want to do.

Comment: The future of your relationship might be boosted by this when you get hauled into court alongside them, @Attilah. Not a good idea. I'd personally ditch the client unless they've got a very, very good reason for doing this.

Comment: "I guess I just have to satisfy the client's request." Part of your role as someone who is supposed to know the technology better than the client, is that your job is to deliver the best product possible that accomplishes their task. You need to look further into what they are trying to do. It's possible that exactly what they want is accomplishable in some other way. Further, if you know exactly what they are trying to do, it gives you more leverage to walk away if it is illegal.

Comment: Stop voting this question down. Others with similar ideas need to see these responses. That said, you client likely doesn't understand the implications of the request and I think you should probe their requirements a bit deeper.

Comment: @Attliah, if you think they want to do something malicious, that's your chance to bail out.

Comment: so, to accomplish this task, I need to learn how to write rootkits ?
I don't even know the basics of rootkits programming or security related programming.

Comment: @Attilah: If you want to be one of those people whose excuse is, "i was only following orders", or "I had to feed my family", then go ahead, but realize that some smart people here can't think of any legitimate reason to do what your client is asking for. That leaves the possibility that they don't know what they're asking for, and the possibility that they _do_ know what they're asking for, and it's illegal or unethical. Maybe make sure a friend knows you asked this in case you disappear.

Comment: This is NOT a "blatantly offensive" question. It is a programming question.

Comment: "Blatantly offensive" seems a cop-out reason to close this question.    I, for one, liked seeing each and every answer mention why this sounds like a slimy goal for an app and good reasons both technically and ethically to avoid it.  Let it ride!

Comment: With computers, there is a way to evade anything on the OS, even if it means rewriting the OS from the ground up, with exceptions for your program. If this guy wanted, he could probably write a hack for sysinternals that filters out his own process. The answers regarding the Kernel execution and things like that, are interesting discussions of the way computers actually work and track processes. These are all good things to come out of a question.

Comment: I voted to reopen.  I can appreciate the concern as the end result from something like this could be bad, however I don't find the question to be "blatantly offensive".  I think this would be a good place to address the reason *why* something like this is hard to implement and why doing something like this would be bad for users.

Comment: Also, if we (as a SO community) find a way around the ProcessMonitor, I imagine one or all of us would report it to the SysInternals team, so that they can fix the security flaw, if it is one.

Comment: @devinb: that's a good argument in favor of doing this sort of research, but (IMHO) not one for making such information available on a website such as this. Responsible security researchers report flaws privately, giving those able to correct them an opportunity to do so, revealing the details publicly only when a patch or work-around is available. Of course, such a patch or work-around would also invalidate any answer posted here describing such a technique... thereby removing any remaining need for such an answer.

Answer (score 19):

One of the uses of [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is to find and remove malicious software that tries to hide from the user:

> Process Monitor is an advanced
>   monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and
>   process/thread activity. It combines
>   the features of two legacy
>   Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and
>   Regmon, and adds an extensive list of
>   enhancements including rich and
>   non-destructive filtering,
>   comprehensive event properties such
>   session IDs and user names, reliable
>   process information, full thread
>   stacks with integrated symbol support
>   for each operation, simultaneous
>   logging to a file, and much more. **Its
>   uniquely powerful features will make
>   Process Monitor a core utility in your
>   system troubleshooting and malware
>   hunting toolkit.**

I am not saying that what you want to do is impossible, rather that you are trying to do something that feels a bit dishonest.

That being said I would like you to consider the fact that you are trying to hide a process from a utility that was written to find anything and everything by folks that are a lot smarter than you and me.

Comment: nice reply, Andrew. you're probably right. thanks.
does anyone else knows how to actually do this ?

Comment: If they do, it is my hope that they won't post how. I can't imagine a good reason for doing this, and would be interested in yours.

Comment: Attilah: I'll repeat what someone else said on a question like this: "I don't know how to do this, and if I figured out a way, I'd report it to Microsoft as a bug."

Answer (score 17):

I'll assume you're not planning to do anything malicious. If that's the case, it's important you don't hide your application from diagnostic tools. You can't guarantee your application is bug free. Even if it is, you can't predict its interaction with other applications. Because of that, you should leave it visible so other technical people can troubleshoot if something goes wrong.

Regarding your comment, "so, I guess I just have to satisfy the client's request" - not if it's illegal or technically dangerous for them. You need to protect yourself and them from bad judgment.

Comment: Yup, +1 for "You need to protect yourself and them from bad judgment"

Answer (score 12):

PM reads data at a very low level so to hide from it you have to actually take over certain NT kernel structures and methods to report different information to PM than what Windows itself sees. Doing this is platform and version dependent ( ie. Windows XP SP1 is different than Windows XP SP2 is different than Vista x64, etc.). It's nearly impossible to do correctly without creating an incredible number of system instability issues.

While it's not strictly illegal, every company that has done it and been discovered (which you will) has enjoyed lots of backlash and criticism from users and security professionals. Again while not explicitly illegal, the kinds of changes required can open severe security holes on the end users' machines. Should they have major system crashes or be exposed to hackers/viruses you may be legally liable for the damage.

Comment: (+1) from me for actually trying to answer the question, while at the same time cautioning the OP from actually doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Possible semi-legitimate (though I wouldn't want my name associated with them) applications you would want to keep people from seeing are DRM enforcers and nanny-cam style monitors for kids and errant spouses.

That said, I don't think your client really wants you to subvert such an important system. They likely want something less rootkit-like but they picked up the vocabulary watching "24" and have failed to adequately express what it is they want done.

My advice would be to go back to them for clarification. If they do indeed want something to be completely undetectable then you need to decide based on your own conscience whether to proceed or leave the client.

Comment: (+1) for going back to the client to determine what they want their application to DO not how they want to do it.